# how to make Select function used in model dynamically select the column to export in excel in Laravel using Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I am working in the project using Laravel 8 and waatwebsite(to work with excel). I have one Table name Docs in my database which have 20 columns value. I dont Know how to make the select() function dynamical so that i can pass the column name from controller to extract the query and dump the column i need for other download.

Here, I have download other data in excel with different column rather then Lc_no, cur, value_date.

Also,
How to set parameter of constructor string $search,string $from, string $to to null if not passed through controller.

**Model**

```
    class UserExport implements FromQuery
    {
        use Exportable;
        /**
        * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
        */
    
    use Exportable;
    
    
    public function __construct(string $search,string $from, string $to)
        {
            
            $this->from = $from;
            $this->to = $to;
            $this->search = $search;
            
        }
    
        public function query()
        {
    
            return Doc::query()->wherebetween($this->search, [$this->from,$this->to])->select('lc_no', 'cur', 'value_date');
        }
```

**Controller**

class ExportController extends Controller
{

```
        function exports(){
            //return Excel::download(new UserExport, 'users.xlsx');
            return (new UserExport)->download('docs.xlsx');
        }
    
    
        function treasury_dump($from,$to)
        {
            $search = 'value_date';
                return (new UserExport($search,$from,$to))->download('treasury.xlsx');
    
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass array as parameter instead of multiple parameter

```
public function __construct($params)
{
            
    $this->params = $params;
            
}
    
public function query()
{
    
    return Doc::query()->wherebetween($this->params['search'], [$this->params['from'],$this->params['to']])->select($this->params['columns']);
}
```

in your controller

```
$params=[
'search'=>'asfsa',
'from'=>'',
'to'=>'',
'columns'=>['lc_no', 'cur', 'value_date']
];

return (new UserExport($params))->download('treasury.xlsx');
```

But make sure if you pass null for search ,from and to query will fail so better check before executing query like below

```
Doc::query()->where(function($query)use(){
if(isset($this->params['search'])&&!empty($this->params['search'])&&isset($this->params['from'])&&!empty($this->params['from'])&&isset($this->params['to'])&&!empty($this->params['to'])){
$query->wherebetween($this->params['search'], [$this->params['from'],$this->params['to']]);
}

)->select($this->params['columns']);
```

**Updated**

```
  Doc::query()->where(function($query) {
        if (isset($this->params['search']) && !empty($this->params['search']) && isset($this->params['from']) && !empty($this->params['from']) && isset($this->params['to']) && !empty($this->params['to'])) {
            $query->wherebetween($this->params['search'], [$this->params['from'], $this->params['to']]);
        }
    }
    )->select($this->params['columns']);
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked..but second Query saying syntax error. for checking null value to search from and to.

Comment: check any syntax error in my code or else which line it throw error

Comment: in first line .....syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Many Many thanx..It is bro it very embarrassing for me to even ask you to solve the syntax error.. I am very new to the programming.. seeing all these nested function confuses me .....:D

Comment: is it working.if its working please accept and vote for the answer

Comment: I would have but i dont have enough reputation to cast a vote...i will do it from my another account

Comment: you can accept answer i guess even though you havent have sufficient points